# Combine 2 different queries with different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I combine the 2 queries below in order to have the result in the same table as 4 columns Table name, last create date, last update date and columns count?

```
select distinct 
    'abc.gcc_case' Table, 
    max(create_date) as Last_Create_Date, 
    max(update_date) as Last_Update_Date 
from abc.gcc_case

select 
    count(*) as Columns_Count 
from information_schema.columns
where Table_name = 'gcc_case'
```

I was trying to use a join but I am not sure what to use to give the result I was looking for.

Comment: Expected results would help immensely

Comment: The expected result would be: 

Table                   Last _Create_Date   Last_Update_Date   Columns_Count
abc.gcc_case         5/8/2023                5/8/2023                  51

and I would be adding additional tables to this as new rows with union.

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results (as formatted text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option

The distinct is redundant

```
  select 'abc.gcc_case' Table
         ,max(create_date) as Last_Create_Date
         ,MAX(update_date) as Last_Update_Date 
         ,(select count(*) as Columns_Count 
            from information_schema.columns
           where Table_name = 'gcc_case'
          ) as column_count
     from abc.gcc_case
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was trying to do without success. It answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Something I noticed is that you want the output of these two queries to be in the a row

```
select * 
from  (

             select distinct 
                'abc.gcc_case' TableTableName, 
                max(create_date) as Last_Create_Date, 
                MAX(update_date) as Last_Update_Date 
            from abc.gcc_case
)List
cross apply (  
               select 
                    count(*) as Columns_Count 
                from information_schema.columns
                where Table_name = 'gcc_case'
        )cot
```

result:

| TableName | Last_Create_Date | Last_Update_Date | Columns_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc.gcc_case | 2020-02-01 | 2020-02-01 | 10 |

Comment: But why use the old comma-join syntax, it's been deprecated for 30 years. Use a proper `CROSS JOIN` or just use a scalar subquery

Comment: I know and I don't use it myself.Because both tables have only one record, I used this method. There are many other methods.I Edited my code